# How long would it take to guess user passwords in a specified range?

Tags: php, security, hash

I am using blowfish in php using the crypt function. I would like to know how long it would take to guess the users passwords if the range of the passwords are 0001 - 9999?

Should I implement another input password value for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically gives you 10,000 combinations and it will be quite fast (instant) to guess it.

Check this old table its much faster now [Password Recovery Speeds](http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi)

Comment: yeah thought so, I just have to explain this to my boss. My bank uses a 4 digit pin with another password input to authenticate. I think thats better. I just wanted to know if I could slow down the brute force attack substantially.

Comment: @samaras, I don't this is your main issue. Banks in Finland use numeric passwords with length of 6, but they use 2-factor authentication and they lock the account after 3 wrong attempts.

Comment: Agree with Adnan I think there should be lock after certain number of attempts as well as after 2 wrong one to add some sort of captcha check

Answer (score 2):

Testing all numeric passwords of size 4 is *extremely fast* on any modern computer. You should make sure that your passwords are composed of **different characters** (upper/lowercase letters, punctuation, special characaters), and are **longer** (10 characters at least, or even more depending on the sensivity of your system).

See [this very interesting article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html) by Jeff Atwood on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you came up with a good combination of hashing speed and usability.

```
more hashing time =~ more brute-force resilient
```

But at the same time

```
more hashing time =~ less usability
```

Assuming you made some compromises and decided that it's okay for a password checking logic to take up to `5` seconds (you did that with a large number of iterations, meaning you hashed the password many many times).

Time to break *(in hours)* = combinations * hashing_time *(in seconds)* / 3600 (+ looking up time, trivial)

Let's try it

Time to break *(in hours)* = 9999 * 5 / 3600 = roughly 13 hours and 48 minutes

So bottom line, follow @[Wookai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56761/wookai)'s advice, don't use short numeric passwords.